# echo text and tail log to pipe to email

Tags: email, pipe, echo, tail

I want to echo text as well as tail the last part of a log to pipe it to email. I can easily do one or the other, but how do I do both without first writing everything to a file and then emailing that? I basically want to combine the below two commands into one to only send out one email.

```
echo "There is an error in the log, see the below for detail" | mail -s "error in the log" xxx@yyy.zzz
```

and

```
tail -n 10 /var/log/error.log | mail -s "error in the log" xxx@yyy.zzz
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [concatenate](https://linux.die.net/man/1/cat) command along with [process substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html):

```
cat <(echo "There is an error in the log, see the below for detail") <(tail -n 10 /var/log/error.log) | mail -s "error in the log" xxx@yyy.zzz
```

Comment: the above works in bash. for sh, try this: echo "There is an error in the log, see the below for detail. Return code was: $? \n\n $(tail -n 10  /var/log/error.log)"